# Send mass emails from multiple emails

Tags: php, email

So, the goal is to send many emails using many emails...

I want to use PHP to do it.

I can send multiple emails using Sendmail and a Gmail Account with SMTP. Another thing I can do is to use  hmailserver to send emails in a similar way than the Gmail method. I can also create multiple accounts but..

What I really want is to automatically use multiple emails to send multiple emails, without having to authenticate each one of them trough the SMTP protocol!

The problem of course is not in PHP, but I think that a solution may require some programming.. Or a mix of things..

Do you think this is possible?

Comment: I have tried both the Gmail and Sendmail methods!

Comment: Are these company marketing emails?  Hello spam king.

Comment: There are services such as Constant Contact, Mailchimp etc. that do and handle bulk emails and legit too.

Comment: "What I " only "want is to automatically use multiple emails to send multiple emails, without having to authenticate each one of them trough the SMTP protocol!"

Comment: I'd like to change my original vote of "too broad" to "unclear". Why you ask? Because, it *is* unclear as to what the real intent is here. Questions like this raise a red flag for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want to be a spam king...

> the goal is to send many emails using many emails...

I presume you mean that you would like to send more than 1 email originating from more than one address.  This is possible.  The to, cc and bcc fields can take more than one email address separated by a comma and the from field can be anything you want.

> I can send multiple emails using Sendmail and a Gmail Account with SMTP

Yes.  Sendmail can be configured to use gmail though smtp.

> Another thing I can do is to use hmailserver to send emails in a similar way than the Gmail method.

This will cause more issues than the gmail solution but more on that in a second.

> What I really want is to automatically use multiple emails to send
>   multiple emails, without having to authenticate each one of them
>   trough the SMTP protocol!

The user the email came from is not necessarily the user that authenticated.  You will never get around the auth issue, and you probably want to use a bulk email service.  Many are available.

So on to the issues.  GMail's outgoing mail server is rate limited.  Setting up MyEmailServer is not going to work due to spam filtering methods.  Even if you setup all of the correct dns records etc, etc, your server will still get banned in less than a day.  You only option is to use a service that is specifically provided for bulk mail.

Comment: I'll tell you what, why don't you use the company SMTP server with sendmail?  Just be prepared to answer the "why are none of or emails getting to anyone" question.

Comment: I don't mind reformulating my question to not using PHP, and using some wild misture of things, like linux or something.. But I really want to be able to do this.

Comment: Why do you need to do this @FábioLinhares? `The question remains.. If a bulk mail service can do it.` Reply: A bulk mail service can authenticate itself as the origin sender.

Comment: I need to eliminate many restrictions at once that concern email sending, but for a legit purpose. This is the best way I can think of doing. Some command line like script/program could also work, I don't know.. I believe that technology shouldn't stop evolving because of the dark side of things..

Comment: I know you're right, but I just wanted to push the boundaries on this..

Comment: @FábioLinhares What did you mean by this exactly? [*"I believe that technology shouldn't stop evolving because of the dark side of things"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925628/send-mass-emails-from-multiple-emails#comment104112834_58925730) - That is unclear for me. And please ping me back directly if you're going to respond, thanks. Edit: I would like you to respond to it, it's a legitimate question.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner - Knowing the consequences of doing something, even thought they're for legit purposes is always good, so tanks anyway.